# How to extract only change data (CDC) in AWS RDS (Postgres database) and dump change data to another RDS postgres instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, etl, amazon-rds, debezium

Is there a way to capture only change data in RDS Postgres instance and write those change records to another RDS Postgres DB instance for later use?

I have looked on few option like using Debezium but it doesn't seems to be helpful as I don't have to actually write to streams.

My requirement is that : 
1) Load all the existing data to another DB at once 
2) Capture the change data (delta) and store in a database (with same replica) and process the change data.

Comment: Does AWS database migration services do what you want?

Comment: @jordanm DMS doesn't suit the exact requirement we have. So we decided to go ahead with read replica. Is there a way we can capture and expose the insert/update/delete activities in RDS read replica of postgres?

Comment: You can use a proxy system to automatically redirect write requests to the master. This appears to be a modern version: https://github.com/CrunchyData/crunchy-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I have followed below steps to implement above scenario:

1) Written a Spring batch job which connects to RDS and does a full load once. 
2) Once the full load is completed, we added logic to export WAL logs for CDC data and then put the data to stream to process further.

Not the very best solution but this solution worked well for the above scenario.

Comment: Did you happen to post your code publicly anywhere? I'm very curious how I would create logic to export the WAL logs and so forth.